# Election rules in full?

Tags: discussion, election

At present, some of the election rules seem a bit diffuse. For example, it seems likely that we'll skip the 'primary' stage if there are not 30 volunteers, but that is not really explicit anywhere. What is not at all clear to me is what happens if we have less nominations than vacancies: this does not seem to be mentioned anywhere. Is there a formal list of the election rules anywhere?

Comment: I guess if there are less nominations than vacancies, they'll close the site due to lack of community involvement.

Comment: @Caramdir. Quite possibly, it's just a bit odd that there is not a formal set of rules, as one gets for example with a trade union or user group (the UK-TUG rules are about 6 pages long!)

Answer (score 6):

The best description of the process that I can find is here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/trilogy-2011-elections-begin/. It seems they have changed things a bit though: The minimum rep requirement is 300 and not 2000.

Comment: That change caught me out: I'd original thought we only had about 30 people eligible, and suddenly it rocketed to nearly 200!

Answer (score 5):

As it says here

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/trilogy-2011-elections-begin/

> Note: If there are 10 or less candidates at the end of this phase [nominations], we skip directly to Election.

I'll make sure the sidebar on the election reflects this, it does not currently. Sorry about that.

Comment: It should say 10 or *fewer* candidates.

Comment: @matt I don't think so, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer

Comment: I stand corrected.  You are right that there is considerable debate on the subject, and both are used fequently.  I should say in the manner of Baker that "'10 or *fewer* candidates'" appears to me not only more elegant than '10 or less candidates', but more strictly proper."